# Fixed Position- CONTENT slide BEHIND menu

Tags: css, position, positioning, frontend

I have a fixed header and my content is sliding behind the header. How would I stop the content from sliding behind it.

To put it phiscially the content and the fixed menu are to pieces of paper. They are carrently behaving as if they are on different planes how would I put them on the "same plane" as if on a table. The second paper should not go under the first.

Comment: Please show the code causing the problem. People could guess, but if you show your code then they can verify what the problem actually is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try putting

```
Clear:both;
```

in the content div(the div sliding behind the header)
If the header is fixed like you say, put the margin top on the content div to the height of the header.
So to put this simply:

```
<div class='header'>

</div>
<div class='content'>

</div>
```

CSS

```
.header{
position:fixed;
width:100%;
height:100px;
}
.content{
margin-top:100px;
}
```